How to interpret the stationarity of a time series data with conflicting results among methods used?
I am testing for stationarity on a time series data and found out that it is non-stationary as shown in the first and third column of the image attached.
I used the visual method, ADF test, and KPSS test. For visual method using ACF plot, I am looking for a slowly decreasing correlation trend in the ACF plot. For the other two, here are the following rules:

ADF test is conducted with the following assumptions:

Null Hypothesis (HO): Series is non-stationary, or series has a unit root.
Alternate Hypothesis(HA): Series is stationary, or series has no unit root.

Conditions to Reject Null Hypothesis(H0):
If (Test statistic < Critical Value) and (p-value < 0.05),
Reject Null Hypothesis(HO), i.e., time series does not have a unit root, meaning it is stationary. It does not have a time-dependent
structure.
Reference: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/statistical-tests-to-check-stationarity-in-time-series-part-1/


The KPSS test is conducted with the following assumptions.

Null Hypothesis (HO): Series is trend stationary or series has no unit root.
Alternate Hypothesis(HA): Series is non-stationary, or series has a unit root.

Note: The hypothesis is reversed in the KPSS test compared to ADF Test.
Conditions to Accept Null Hypothesis(H0)
If the (Test Statistic < Critical Value) and (p-value < 0.05),
Accept Null Hypothesis(H0), i.e., time series does not have a unit
root, meaning it is trend stationary.
Reference: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/statistical-tests-to-check-stationarity-in-time-series-part-1/

After knowing that the data is non-stationary, I performed 1st order differencing wherein I used the diff() method on a Pandas Series. Even though the data looks like stationary at first glance on the ACF plot shown and ADF test results on the second column, the KPSS test results suggests otherwise due to the p-value being greater than 0.05. So, I tried increasing the differencing order up to 15th wherein the p-value became less than 0.05 but with the KPSS Test Statistic value being greater than the critical value at 5% as shown on the fourth column. I tried further increasing the differencing order and the p-value kept decreasing while the KPSS Test Statistic value kept increasing which still made it non-stationary.
With those said, I am conflicted whether to consider the data as stationary or non-stationary after 15th order differencing. Am I missing something? How to interpret the stationarity of a time series data with conflicting results among the aforementioned methods used?
Note: I am transforming non-stationary series to stationary to perform ARIMA and SARIMAX modeling on my time series data and it must be stationary to find the optimal "p" and "q" parameters.

